# How to use compile time constants to generate a function name in Rust?

Tags: rust, macros, paste, simd

In SIMD, there are functions like `i8x16_abs`, `u16x8_abs` and `f32x4_abs` .etc.

In order to reduce redundancy, I decided to use macro to call the corresponding function name by specifying data type. Like:

```
simd_abs!(i8)  // Call `i8x16_abs`
simd_abs!(u16) // Call `u16x8_abs`
```

I found some crates like `paste`. However, I don't kown how to pass the compile time constant's value in macro.

```rust
macro_rules! simd_abs_inner {
    ($typ: ty, $chunks: expr) => {
        paste! { [< $typ x $chunks _abs> ] }
    };
}

macro_rules! simd_abs {
    ($typ: ty) => {
        // The `chunks` variable should be a compile time constant
        const chunks: usize = 16 / mem::size_of::<$typ>();
        simd_abs_inner!($typ, chunks)(/*...*/)
    };
}
```

When `$typ` is `i8`, the real called function is `i8xchunks_abs`. The problem is that `chunks` varibale is not a literal so `paste` just replace it by its variable's name. But the compiler do know the `chunks`'s value in the compile time. How to use compile time constants to generate a function name in Rust?

Comment: Constant evaluation takes place *after* macro expansion, so I don't think this is possible.